# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960 Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Sanjai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor'

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, protractor

When I run "protractor conf.js" I faced no problem till I install protractor globally "npm install -g protractor".
After installing protractor global, I got following Error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Sanjai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: I'm not familiarized in protractor but in general terms seems that some of your libraries expect to protractor it in `node_modules`. Try to add it in your `package.json` and run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Hi after some research i got solution for my question.
After deleting all protractor and webdriver related files from the location
'C:\Users{userName}\AppData\Roaming\npm'

And do 'npm install protractor' from the above location, you can get rid of this issue.